# How to print the values in the same input text field using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, calculator

I have created 5 input text boxes using HTML and made a button while clicking the button the values will print the result input text box. The first 4 fields are my inputs and the last text field is my output. unable to debug the issue. kindly find the code and help to find the issue.

```js
function JS(){
            var h=document.getElementById('h').value;
            var w=document.getElementById('w').value;
      var g=document.getElementById('g').value;
      var t=document.getElementById('t').value;
      
      var total =(h+w+g+t);
      
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=total; 
      

}
```

```html
<h2> Calculator</h2>
        
            <input type="text" placeholder="value1" id="h">
            <input type="text"  placeholder="value2"id="w">
      <input type="text" placeholder="value3" id="g">
      <input type="text" placeholder="value4" id="t">
      <input type="text" placeholder="result" id="result">
      <!--
      <p
      id="result">
      </p>
            -->
            <button id="btn" onClick="JS()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=total;` instead of innerHTML, use value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two keys to resolving your issue:

1. Coerce your inputs to numbers, which I'm doing by adding a `+` in front of the value assignments. If you don't do this, your values may be treated like strings and *concatenated* rather than *added* like numbers.
2. Set the `value` of the input element, not the `innerHTML`. If you'd rather use a `<p>` element, which it appears you commented out in your sample code (and which I restored for completeness of my answer), consider using `innerText`.

See example here:

```js
function JS() {
  var h = +document.getElementById('h').value;
  var w = +document.getElementById('w').value;
  var g = +document.getElementById('g').value;
  var t = +document.getElementById('t').value;
  let p_result = document.getElementById('p_result');

  var total = (h + w + g + t);

  document.getElementById('result').value = total;
  p_result.innerText = total;


}
```

```html
<h2> Calculator</h2>

<input type="text" placeholder="value1" id="h">
<input type="text" placeholder="value2" id="w">
<input type="text" placeholder="value3" id="g">
<input type="text" placeholder="value4" id="t">
<input type="text" placeholder="result" id="result">
<br>
<p id="p_result" style="color:red;"></p>
<br>
<button id="btn" onClick="JS()">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function JS(){
            var h=document.getElementById('h').value;
            var w=document.getElementById('w').value;
      var g=document.getElementById('g').value;
      var t=document.getElementById('t').value;
      
      var total =(Number(h)+Number(w)+Number(g)+Number(t));
      
      document.getElementById('result').value =total; 
      

}
```

- `.value` instead of  `.innerHTML`
- also, you should convert inputs values to number cause instead of making the sum will be as consider them string( for example if you type 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 without converting to number will be 1234 if you convert to number will be 10